# После обновления Unity3d вся сцена розовая

Tags: unity3d

После обновления до 5.4.0 обновлённые проекты стали полностью розовыми.

При создании нового проекта вся сцена розовая. Задний фон, террайн итп розовые.

3D объекты (куб,сфера) в новом проекте  белые , но при обновлении старых проектов - розовые.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь пишут http://unity3d.com/ru/unity/beta/unity5.4.0b5:
UI: If the UI shader is not found the default "pink" shader will be used

**Обновлено**

На другом компьютере проверено (пиксельные шейдеры 3.0). Всё работает.

Это может быть из-за того что шейдеры на этом компьютере 2.0?

Comment: загружайте проект через импорт/экспорт из предыдущей версии

Comment: не помогло.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

после обновления столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Возможно проблемы со стандартным Skybox. в моем случае проблемы были именно в нем
[image: После обновления]

[image: Манипуляции со skybox]

Comment: думаю дело в моей видеокарте

Comment: у меня Radeon X1250 на 256 мб. если взять сторонний skybox и применить свой материал к террейну, то все хорошо отлично выглядит. обновление отлично планку для видеокарт подняло. как вариант, можно до сих пор использовать предыдущую версию

Answer (score 2):

Сцена стала розовой, потому что видеокарта не понимает какой шейдер нужно применить к объектам. Ваши объекты потеряли свои материалы - посмотрите свойство-материал, у объектов, ставших розовыми, скорее всего там стоит **none** или **missing** поставьте необходимый материал/текстуру вашим объектам и все должно нормализоваться.

Comment: Исправлено у 3д объектов. Но Стандартный террайн тоже без материала. Почему стандартный террайн материал Built in Standard тоже не отображается?

Comment: Попробуйте  `file menu Assets > Reimport All`

Comment: не помогло...............

Answer (score 0):

Возможно подойдет для террайрена:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Colors -> background
```